# if Checkbox is checked or input:text has value

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox, input

I have a function, which should check if **input:text** has value or if **checkbox is checked**. if not then popup appeares. It works only with checked/unchecked input, and not with input:text. What am I doing wrong here:

```
$("#wcv-product-edit #save_button").click(function(){
    var checked = $("#shipping input:checked" ).length > 0;
    var text_value = $("#shipping input:text" ).length > 0;
    var store_checked = $("#store_shipping input:checked").length > 0;

    if (!checked && !store_checked || !text_value && !store_checked){
        $('#ship_wrong_popup').show();
        $('.page .wcv-tabs .tabs-nav li a.shipping').addClass('ship_highlight');
        return false;
    } else if (!checked && store_checked || !text_value && store_checked){
        // $('#ship_wrong_popup').show();  
        return true;
    } else if (checked && store_checked || text_value && store_checked){
        // $('#ship_wrong_popup').show();  
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: try changing `input:text` to `input[type=text]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var text_value = $("#shipping input:text" ).length > 0;
```

This is **not** only selecting "non-empty" textboxes, it is selecting *any* input of `type="text"` *regardless of whether or not it is empty.* As long as a textbox exists within `#shipping`, this will never be 0.

---

If you only have one textbox, check the `length` of the *value* instead of the element count:

```
var text_value = $("#shipping input:text" ).val().length > 0;
```

If you have more than one textbox and want to see if *all* of them have content, you can filter out empty inputs from the element count by using `.filter`:

```
var text_value = $('#shipping input:text').filter(function () {
    return !!this.value;
}).length;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such an easy mistake :)